# How to control image height to match adjoining text in html email

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have this **html in my email**:
        `<li><h4>Sample Text 31 <small><img src="<link to image>"></small></h4></li>`

The image is misaligned and the height width of the img tag is way bigger than the text size. See below

[image]

How can I keep the image to appear next to text and be of the same size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support most email clients, I would put this content in an actual table and you can use the `valign` attribute if you need to. `valign` doesn't seem necessary in chrome here, but it might be for outlook. You would add `valign="middle"` to the `td`'s. You might also be able to put the text and image together in a single `td` and use `valign="middle"`.

You should be able to nest a `table` in the `li`, or just use a table there instead.

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size:40px;font-weight:bold;">Sample Text 31</td>
    <td><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Speaker_Icon.svg" width="20" height="20"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can display the li tag as a table and its children as cells. then vertical align the contents in the middle

snippet below

```css
li {
 display:table;
  vertical-align:middle;

}
li *{
  display:table-cell;
  border:solid red;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<li><h4>Sample Text 31 </h4><small><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTbmbMn9M5hlfXUXtw0a_ZsH3aS0HWvXT0eZiDeFauNmJOInHgm"></small></li>
```

Comment: according to [campaignmonitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) the `display` property isn't supported in outlook or gmail.